# How to query data from database using multiple key and value in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have tried this but it is returning empty array.

```
    $arr = [];
    foreach($request->spec_id as $key=>$id){
        $arr[$id] = $request->spec[$key];
    }

    $arr = array_filter($arr);

    Ex: $arr = [
                6 => "2000",
                9 => "Petrol"
               ];

    $data = DB::table('categories as c')
        ->join('postads as p','c.id','p.category_id')
        ->join('postad_specifications as ps','p.id','ps.postad_id')
        ->join('specifications as s','ps.specification_id','s.id')
        ->where('p.category_id',$request->category_id)
        ->where(function($query) use($arr){
            foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
            $query->where('ps.specification_id',$key);
            $query->where('ps.value',$value);
            }
        })
        ->select('p.id','p.ad_title')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

The result i want is from **postads** table where **ps.specification_id** and **ps.value** matches with key and value. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: In postad_specifications the id columns isn't your specification_id ?

Comment: No, The postad_specifications has specification_id column separately..

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_keys, array_values functions,
and use whereIn in Laravel

```
    $arr = [];
    foreach($request->spec_id as $key=>$id){
        $arr[$id] = $request->spec[$key];
    }

    $arr = array_filter($arr);

    Ex: $arr = [
                6 => "2000",
                9 => "Petrol"
               ];

    $arrKeys = array_keys($arr);
    $arrValues = array_values($arr);

    $data = DB::table('categories as c')
        ->join('postads as p','c.id','p.category_id')
        ->join('postad_specifications as ps','p.id','ps.postad_id')
        ->join('specifications as s','ps.specification_id','s.id')
        ->where('p.category_id',$request->category_id)
        ->whereIn('ps.specification_id', $arrKeys)
        ->whereIn('ps.value', $arrValues)
        ->select('p.id','p.ad_title')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

Comment: I want the exact post which matches the array index and value..